# "Fatal Error" following nutch tutorial "markup in the document following the root must be well formed"

Tags: java, xml, nutch

I'm following the tutorial for Apache Nutch.

I have the conf/nutch-site.xml configured like so:

```
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>Nutch Spidah</value>
</property>

<configuration>

</configuration>
```

I'm getting this error:

[Fatal Error] nutch-site.xml:11:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

I know I'm missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your properties must appear inside the configuration tags:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>http.agent.name</name>
      <value>Nutch Spidah</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

See this [example](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/nutch-site.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the configuration tags around the property tags